# Update non model field class variables i Django models

Tags: python, django

I have a django model which has a JSONField, it stores all the neccessary things.
I have to use JSONField to collect data insted of normal fields.

My model looks like this.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    json_content = JSONField(default=dict)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value1 = self.json_content
        self.value2 = self.json_content
```

I want to have some class variables (value1, value2) , which I want to update during model initialisation.
I will use this as :

```
m = MyModel()
m.value2 = 'some thing'
```

But json_content is not taking JSONField data during initialisation. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your second snippet shows you are not passing in any data during initialisation. So overriding the `__init__` method is completely pointless, and you should remove that code.